# MAMP : Mysql won't turn on

Tags: mysql, mamp

My mamp mysql server won't turn on. I tried executing /Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh but that gave me this error :

> 101110 05:50:31 mysqld_safe Logging to
>   '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err'.
>
> 101110 05:50:32 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from
>   /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
>
> 101110 05:50:32 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file
>   /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended

/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err :

> InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
>
> InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
>
> InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
>
> InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
>
> InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
>
> InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
>
> InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do
>   not
>
> InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
>
> 101110  5:53:08 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>
> 101110  5:53:08 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE
>   ENGINE  failed.
>
> 101110  5:53:08 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port:
>   Address  already in use
>
> 101110  5:53:08 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server
>   running  on port: 3306 ?
>
> 101110  5:53:08 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 101110  5:53:08 [Warning] Forcing shutdown of 2 plugins
>
> 101110  5:53:08 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld:
>   Shutdown  complete
>
> 101110 05:53:08 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file
>   /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended

Comment: Could you post the contents of the '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err' file?

Comment: It just all of a sudden started working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm glad for you it fixed itself on its own ;)

From the look of your error file, it looks like you already had an instance of MySQL running... Not sure if this works on a mac, but you could try :

```
pidof mysqld
```

If this outputs something (one or several numbers), then MySQL is running. If the output is empty, then it is not.

Comment: `pidof` doesn't seem to be on lion. I'd generally use something like `ps aux | grep mysqld` for that.

Comment: or brew install pidof

Answer (score 12):

twob.net has a pretty good fix for it. 
Go Into terminal and type in

```
killall -9 mysqld
```

Check it - http://twob.net/journal/fix-for-mamp-mysql/. Worked for me

Comment: I tried by still error. can you give me another solution?

Answer (score 8):

What I have found is that at times more than one occurrence of mysql is running. What I do when MySQL will not start is I first quit MAMP, then I go into the Applications/utlities and open the Activity Monitor. From there I search for "my" which should bring up any mysql's that may be running. I then either quit or force quit mysql. At that point I'm able to open MAMP with a working MySQL server.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

This command worked for me.

```
     ps aux | grep mysql 
     lsof -i 
     killall -9 mysqld
```

if needed

```
    sudo killall -9 mysqld
```

Ref: http://www.witheringtree.com/2010/05/how-to-resolve-mysql-not-starting-in-mamp/

Answer (score 3):

With a new/clean install of MAMP 4.1.1, I had the same problem.

When running:
 `/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh`

MySql reported:

`mysqld_safe error: log-error set to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err', however file don't exists. Create writable for user 'mysql'.`.

So, I ran `touch /Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err` and tried again with `startMysql.sh`.  It worked (but it wasn't quite "by itself")!

Answer (score 1):

other way that might fix the same problem :

-go in the folder MAMP/db/mysql/ – delete all files that IS NOT A FOLDER (files like ‘mysql-bin.XXXXXX’ / ‘mysql-bin.index’/ ‘ibdata1’ / ‘ib_logfileX’

don’t worry, this doesn’t erase any of your database, but make sure you don’t delete the folders. That’s where the data of your databases are stored.

Answer (score 1):

There's another reason why this could be happening and I don't see anyone mentioning it, so I'll explain it in this answer.

When you reboot your computer, sometimes you force-close the apps and MAMP is not able to shutdown MySQL properly which leaves the socket file intact instead of MySQL removing it cleanly as part of its shutdown process. From what I understand (sources needed), MySQL used to make a socket file verification if it was forced to shutdown before, but it's not doing it anymore. Here's what you need to do:

1. Make sure no MySQL instance is still running by typing `killall -9 mysqld` in terminal, then press enter to execute the command. It will shut down all the leftover mysql instances running.
2. Go to /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql
3. Find the mysql.sock file and delete it. It could be named mysql.sock.lock as well.
4. Restart MAMP.

Everything should be booting up and running fine now. If not or if you can't find the mysql.sock file, your issue could be another one mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Jmeyer, on occasion MAMP will do strange things like refuse to restart. When this happens, go to the MAMP application and click "preferences" and then just click "Ok."

For some reason this forces a restart of the MAMP server.

Not sure if that's what you were looking for, but a helpful tip nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

This is what did it for me, in terminal:

sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to fix this - usually one works.

To start off, try quitting MAMP and then:

```
sudo killall -9 mysqld
```

If that fails, try going to Preferences > Ports and changing to MAMP default. Click ‘OK’. MySQL should then start. If your website doesn’t show up at `localhost`, try changing the ports back.

You can also stop MAMP, go to System Preferences > MySQL and turn off MySQL and then restart MAMP.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another gotcha:
Check who is the owner of `/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err`

On my machine, it is owned by `admin: admin`.
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh` will fail to start, even if run with sudo.

But this will work:

```
sudo su admin
/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh
```