# mysql not starting in MAMP for Mac

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mamp

I have tried killing the process from Terminal but no process found. Not found in Activity Monitor either.

Tried to find the ib_logN files, still no luck.

Played with moving files, folder from Application to desktop and back.

Installed, Re-installed but the mysql is not starting. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Any potential clues in the log file?

Comment: Paul, I did not find the log file. The Log folder has file named apache_error.log but not for mysql

Comment: Hi Paul, Response from D. Woods in the link below fixed my problem . Thanks for checking.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145182/mamp-mysql-wont-turn-on

Comment: Ok, no problem, at least you got it working!