# MySQL server doesn't run via MAMP on mac OS

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I upgraded my MAMP PRO 3.5.2 version to the 5th and MySQL start fails.

I killed mysqld processes via `killall -9 mysqld`, cleaned log files like  `ib_logfile*` and tried manipulations with `innodb recovery`.

The log I've got looks like this:

`2018-10-10T14:16:12.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
2018-10-10T14:16:12.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57
2018-10-10T14:16:13.043096Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2018-10-10T14:16:13.051110Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.23) starting as process 5538 ...
2018-10-10T14:16:13.064223Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ is case insensitive
2018-10-10T14:16:13.074890Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-10-10T14:16:13.074926Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-10-10T14:16:13.074936Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-10-10T14:16:13.074943Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-10-10T14:16:13.074972Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2018-10-10T14:16:13.079521Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-10-10T14:16:13.084840Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-10-10T14:16:13.089357Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-10-10T14:16:13.114376Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-10-10T14:16:13.140491Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-10-10T14:16:13.145746Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number 527111 in space 0, space name innodb_system, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read. If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.
2018-10-10T14:16:13.145772Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Server exits.
2018-10-10T14:16:13.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended`

Would appreciate any hint which direction to go as I start to consider to uninstall and reinstall of MAMP which means I will lose few local DB installations.

Thanks!

Comment: There are some commands here that can help you. I looked at your error and it has to be the same with him. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145182/mamp-mysql-wont-turn-on

Comment: thanks for suggestion @ChristianGallarmin I tried things mentioned there and they didn't work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was solved and MySQL runs locally via MAMP 5.1.

While figuring out what was going wrong in the `my.cnf` following settings were applied:

- increased `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value: `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M`
- force recovery mode was on `innodb_force_recovery = 1`

That lead to the error that mentioned in the question:

`[ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number 527111 in space 0, space name innodb_system, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read. If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.`

At this point default settings for the `ibdata` dir and path were uncommented inside of `my.cnf`:

`innodb_data_home_dir = "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57"`

`innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend`

`innodb_log_group_home_dir = "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57"`

Error log was reported on access limits (don't have an exact sentence at front of me), was lost a bit here, and as a guess measure, I extended rights for the folder `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57` to my current user.

That didn't change the log. The error about a wrong path to the `ibdata` was still there.

**In the end the renaming of the folder `mysql` (where was the full version of `ibdata` (~40Gb)) to `mysql57` helped.**

There was following folder structure in `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/` after the installation of MAMP 5.1:

`-- mysql`

`-- mysql56_TIMESTAMP`

`-- mysql57`

with the same structure of files, but a closer comparison of the content showed that the full version of the file inside of `mysql`, so renamed it, and removed all folders after tests that MAMP works correctly without them.

So now I have only one `mysql` folder inside of `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/`. The settings inside of `my.cnf` that I customized in the process rolled back.

Comment: I was having the same problem, your solution worked! Thank you.